# Error reading arrays from csv files in Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, file

I have a problem reading the first column of the csv file with numpy. All the values of the first column gets returned as `nan` instead of `[   2.    4. 1120.]` and such.

```
import genfromtxt from numpy 
my_data = genfromtxt('input.csv', delimiter=',')
first_column = len(my_data[:,0]) - 1
```

Inside the csv file:

```
[   2.    4. 1120.],67.8,63.7,-676.1,-365.2,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-608.3000000000001,-301.5
[  2.    4.5 100. ],0.0,0.0,-0.30000000000000004,-0.7,0.0,0.0,99.7002,0.0,0.0,-0.30000000000000004,-0.7
[   2.    4. 1130.],70.8,52.2,-672.7,-346.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,-601.9000000000001,-294.3
[  2.    4.5 110. ],0.0,0.2,-0.7,-0.1,0.0,0.0,99.3010995,0.0,0.0,-0.7,0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your import sentence is inverted. It should be:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
```

Second, apparently `genfromtxt()` cannot convert the string `'[   2.    4. 1120.]'` to float as it does with all the other values in the array so that's why it returns `nan`.
The same occurs with `numpy.loadtxt()`.

An option to not "lose" those values can be reading the csv file with `pandas`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

my_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv').to_numpy()
```

Where `my_data` contains:

```
array([['[  2.    4.5 100. ]', 0.0, 0.0, -0.30000000000000004, -0.7, 0.0,
        0.0, 99.7002, 0.0, 0.0, -0.30000000000000004, -0.7],
       ['[   2.    4. 1130.]', 70.8, 52.2, -672.7, -346.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0, -601.9000000000002, -294.3],
       ['[  2.    4.5 110. ]', 0.0, 0.2, -0.7, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0,
        99.3010995, 0.0, 0.0, -0.7, 0.1]], dtype=object)
```

Although you will still need to parse every value on the first column to convert them to numpy arrays.
For that, you can use `np.fromstring` but you will need to avoid the brackets characters in order for it to work as expected.

Without avoiding brackets you will see an error message:

```
np.fromstring(my_data[:, 0], sep=' ')
```

```
<ipython-input-65-7d75c8d121f5>:1: DeprecationWarning: string or file could not be read to its end due to unmatched data; this will raise a ValueError in the future.
  np.fromstring(my_data[:, 0], sep=' ')
```

Unfortunately, to avoid brackets you will need to loop the array:

```
for i, row in enumerate(my_data[:, 0]):
    my_data[i, 0] = np.fromstring(data[i, 0][1:-1], sep=' ').astype(np.float32)
```

By indexing with `[1:-1]`, is "removing" the bracket characters before passing the values to `np.fromstring`.

After that, `my_data` will contain numpy arrays in the first column:

```
array([[array([  2. ,   4.5, 100. ], dtype=float32), 0.0, 0.0,
        -0.30000000000000004, -0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 99.7002, 0.0, 0.0,
        -0.30000000000000004, -0.7],
       [array([   2.,    4., 1130.], dtype=float32), 70.8, 52.2, -672.7,
        -346.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -601.9000000000002, -294.3],
       [array([  2. ,   4.5, 110. ], dtype=float32), 0.0, 0.2, -0.7,
        -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 99.3010995, 0.0, 0.0, -0.7, 0.1]], dtype=object)
```

So the first column would have:

```
print(my_data[:, 0])
```

```
array([array([  2. ,   4.5, 100. ], dtype=float32),
       array([   2.,    4., 1130.], dtype=float32),
       array([  2. ,   4.5, 110. ], dtype=float32)], dtype=object)
```

Although is an elaborated solution, it works. Maybe there is a better or simpler way without the need to loop the array in order to make the conversion.

Comment: @tonyselcuk, Please update your question including the code you tried to implement and the error message. Otherwise no one can know what happened except you.

Comment: I did a different function thanks anyways